# How to make the unit length of $x$ axis and that of $y$ axis the same?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I use Tikz to draw the graphs of $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=5(x-\frac{4}{3})$, but I found the unit length of $x$ axis and that of $y$ axis are different, if I want to let them be the same, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you looking for `unit vector ratio=1 1 1`?

Comment: Unrelated note: TikZ and `pgfplots` are two separate packages. The latter uses the former, but one can make plots in TikZ without using `pgfplots`.   That `unit vector ratio` worked means that you use `pgfplots` I guess, so it's better to say that. (By the the way, `axis equal` is a shorthand for `unit vector ratio=1 1 1`.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. wow great advice!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The pgfplots manual says on p. 299: "The configuration `axis equal image=true` is actually just a style which sets `unit vector ratio=1 1 1,unit rescale keep size=false`." so that I think that there is a slight difference (which however does not matter here). And yes, I guessed from the context that pgfplots was used since Ti*k*Z alone does not rescale units.

Comment: @marmot Oops, you're right. I must have misread, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @marmot well, it was not a good advice at all... `:P`.

Answer (score 5):

You can enforce equal units by saying `unit vector ratio=1 1 1`, `axis equal image` or `axis equal`. The differences are subtle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    f(\x) = \x+1/\x;
    g(\x) = 5*(\x-4/3);}] 
\begin{axis}[unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5,ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=0,xmax=5.5,xlabel=$x$,
    domain=0.1:5,samples=101,
    legend pos=south east]
\addplot [blue,thick] {f(x)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}
\addplot [red,thick] {g(x)};
\addlegendentry{$g(x)$}
\end{axis}
\node[anchor=north] at (current axis.south) {\texttt{unit vector ratio=1 1 1}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
~
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    f(\x) = \x+1/\x;
    g(\x) = 5*(\x-4/3);}] 
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5,ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=0,xmax=5.5,xlabel=$x$,
    domain=0.1:5,samples=101,
    legend pos=south east]
\addplot [blue,thick] {f(x)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}
\addplot [red,thick] {g(x)};
\addlegendentry{$g(x)$}
\end{axis}
\node[anchor=north] at (current axis.south) {\texttt{axis equal image}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
~
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
    f(\x) = \x+1/\x;
    g(\x) = 5*(\x-4/3);}] 
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    ymin=-5, ymax=5,ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=0,xmax=5.5,xlabel=$x$,
    domain=0.1:5,samples=101,
    legend pos=south east]
\addplot [blue,thick] {f(x)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}
\addplot [red,thick] {g(x)};
\addlegendentry{$g(x)$}
\end{axis}
\node[anchor=north] at (current axis.south) {\texttt{axis equal}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]